# Catch error message inside command substitution

Tags: bash

My question is about this command inside a shell script :

```
dirpath=$(zenity --file-selection --directory 2> /dev/null)
```

When I type the above command inside a terminal, everything goes fine, the error message is hidden.
But inside my script, it seems that the usual "2> /dev/null" won't do anything.

Does anyone understand what's going on ?

thx

Comment: It should work fine. What are you seeing that makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: When I run my script and I choose to create a new folder with Zenity, I get the following message I would like to hide : (zenity:6010): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_set_object: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

Comment: You get that where exactly? That might be going to standard output instead of standard error. But I'd be more concerned about why that error is happening in the first place.

Comment: All I can tell you is that the message is hidden when I type the above command in the Gnome terminal (the error message shows if I remove the redirection). It isn't when I run my script.

Comment: It is possible that zenity is detecting the environment and sending the message to different places I suppose. Are you using the same shell for the script and your interactive session? `strace -o zenity.log -tt zenity ....` in both situations would tell us what (if anything) it was doing differently if you want to dig further.

Comment: Yes I'm using Gnome terminal for both

Comment: How are you running the script? Just `/path/to/script.sh` from your normal terminal window?

Comment: The log file I get with your command is 9400 lines  long ! I don't know where to look for ...

Comment: Just typing    ./myscript

Comment: One possibility is that there simply *is* no error when you run from the terminal, and that the error when it does occur is being written directly to the terminal, rather than to standard error.

Comment: Yeah but the redirection 2> for standard error is working here

Comment: Yeah, strace is verbose (and I didn't know offhand what filtering I needed and didn't want to get it wrong). You can upload it somewhere (pastebin/gist/etc.) and link to it in a comment.

Comment: Everything's my fault cause I didn't change the command in the right place of my code. So STUPID from me i didn't check that twice ... I can't apologize enough. Anyway thanks for ur help Etan and everybody, I'll be far more careful next time.... and I learnt a few things with your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be true here, but when BASH fails a command parse, you get the error message sent to stderr without redirection.  If you really want to squelch error messages, this always works:

```
dirpath=$(exec 2>/dev/null
    zenity --file-selection --directory)
```